# React - update component when different component changed state

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have in header component dropdown which behave like a filter for whole my application. Lets say I got grid component in my layout its filled with some data, for example list of cars which were available in some year. When I select from my dropdown in header year, I want to update my grid component to contain only cars which were available in selected year.

Here is my reducer with action creator for dropdown in header component. I removed some code for brevity.

```
export interface IImporterSelectorContextState {
    dataQuery?: ServiceApi.IDataQuery;
    data?: any[];
    context?: ServiceApi.IDocumentContext
}    
type KnownAction = 
    IChangeCurrentContext

export const actionCreators = {
    changeYearContext: (context: ServiceApi.IDocumentContext) : AppThunkAction<KnownAction> => (dispatch, getState) => {
        dispatch(changeCurrentContext(context));
    }
}

const unloadedState: IImporterSelectorContextState = {
   //removed for brevity
};

export const reducer: Reducer<IImporterSelectorContextState> = (state: IImporterSelectorContextState,
    incomingAction: Action) => {

    const action = incomingAction as KnownAction;
    switch (action.type) {
        case CHANGE_CURRENT_CONTEXT:
            return {
                ...state,
                context: action.context
            }
        default:
            const exhaustiveCheck: never = action;
    }
    return state || unloadedState;
}
```

When year is selected, `changeYearContext` function is called, my state is set to new values for header component. I dont know exactly how can I update my grid component where cars are shown. To get new data based on my filter, i have to send new request (got button for that) to get new data, but I want to refresh data when new year from dropdown is selected. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by two way:

Method 1: the simplest, bind an event hanlder using `onChange` property of your select component, like this:

```
import {Component} from 'react'
class MyHeaderComponent extends Component{
  render(){
    return (
      <select onChange={(e)=>this.changeYearHandler(e.target.value)}>
        <option></option>
        ...
      </select>
    )
  }
  changeYearHandler(value){
    fetch(MY_API_URI, /* and pass value with post json or other way*/).then(data=>{
      // give it to redux via prop bound with react-redux's connect method
      this.props.changeYearContext(data)
    })
  }
}
```

Method 2: use redux-saga and implement request as a side effect of changing the redux state, with this method, first, you change the year state, and then, your data is loaded and pushed to the state,
I suggest you to read the doc from https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga

Comment: I found a working solution via using `componentWillReceiveProps` function where I have to check out if props have been changed and then do something. Dunno if its correct solution to this, but it works as I want.

Comment: componentWillReceiveProps is now deprecated and replaced by static method getDerivedStateFromProps

see https://hackernoon.com/replacing-componentwillreceiveprops-with-getderivedstatefromprops-c3956f7ce607

componentWillReceiveProps or getDerivedStateFromProps  is not a good place to trigger side effects, it's purpose is to update state, you should use componentDidUpdate instead for your side effects by comparison like ajax calls

Comment: Good to know, so I moved it to componentDidUpdate lifecycle method. Thanks